# Executing a random method

Tags: ruby, methods

I am trying to make a logic for executing a random method. Let's say for example I have 10 methods, I need to run one of them selected at random.

The main method will reside in the ActionController of my Rails 3.2 app which will have the logic and the 10 methods inside.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When you say "I am trying to make a logic" it would really help to post a little code from one of your attempts, otherwise it does look like you are asking someone else to do your work for you. Questions asking for code, but not showing any effort are off topic on Stack Overflow. Please add a couple of lines of *your* code to keep it on topic, because it's an interesting question but will otherwise get closed.

Comment: I'll elaborate on the idea a little bit , may be someone else will make a gem out of that as i am too newbie for that. So an idea came to my mind after seeing lots of captcha options.But I was looking for very simple option.What i am thinking is how can we use the hexadecimal random number generated by rails via securerandom and use it for captacha. In pseudo code it should be like,
secret = randomnumber via securerandom
method(secret, answer, question) { 
question.randomise
answer.question
return ans, que, secret}
Ex Ques logic : Take secret and find out the third letter from the left

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pick a random method from an array using [`sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), then use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
# Make a few methods
def a; 1; end
def b; 2; end
def c; 3; end
def d; 4; end
def e; 5; end

# Put their names in an array
methods = %i[a b c d e]

# Call a random one
send methods.sample  #=> 4
send methods.sample  #=> 1
send methods.sample  #=> 3
```

Comment: Nice.  Note that if class A contains these and only these methods, `A.instance_methods(false) => [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]`--your array `methods`.  This might be handy if the list of methods changes over time, lest one forget to update `methods`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just don’t forget to remove the random-calling method if it’s also in A lest you end up recursing with a randomly-applied base case!

Comment: Good point. As I said, I was assuming class A would contain only those methods, but if it were in class A, I guess you could either check for it when looping through methods, or better: methods = A.instance_methods(false) - [:random_caller]